# how to use PL SQL functions to made xml report from xmltype data

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am new in pl/sql and xml.I store the following xml data inside oracle table.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <Programmer>
            <Salary>2000</Salary>
            <Facilities>
                <Car>bmw</Car>
                <Apartment>1</Apartment>
                <Bonus>2000</Bonus>
            </Facilities>
        </Programmer>
        <Manager>
            <Salary>1500</Salary>
            <Facilities>
                <Car>ford</Car>
                <Room>1</Room>
                <Bonus>1500</Bonus>
            </Facilities>
        </Manager>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

I want to write function like this:

`getEmployee('Programmer');`

Which return following Result:

```
<Programmer>
    <Salary>2000</Salary>
     <Facilities>
         <Car>bmw</Car>
         <Apartment>1</Apartment>
         <Bonus>2000</Bonus>
    </Facilities>
    </Programmer>
```

So how to write such functions.Please help.Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. I am storing xml  as xmltype column.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen.Can you please show me some code examples.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a PL/SQL function for returning parts of an XML document. You can just use the `XQuery` functionality to directly `SELECT` parts of an XML documents. This also means that you can still create a PL/SQL function around the `XQuery` `SELECT` if you would like to hide the query itself:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTEST (xmlcol XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO XMLTEST (xmlcol) VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <Programmer>
            <Salary>2000</Salary>
            <Facilities>
                <Car>bmw</Car>
                <Apartment>1</Apartment>
                <Bonus>2000</Bonus>
            </Facilities>
        </Programmer>
        <Manager>
            <Salary>1500</Salary>
            <Facilities>
                <Car>ford</Car>
                <Room>1</Room>
                <Bonus>1500</Bonus>
            </Facilities>
        </Manager>
    </Employee>
</Company>');

COMMIT;

SELECT XMLQUERY('//Programmer' PASSING xmlcol RETURNING CONTENT)
  FROM XMLTEST;

<Programmer>
  <Salary>2000</Salary>
  <Facilities>
    <Car>bmw</Car>
    <Apartment>1</Apartment>
    <Bonus>2000</Bonus>
  </Facilities>
</Programmer>
```

**NOTE:** The above query would extract any tag that is called "Programmer" due to the usage of the double slashes in the QXuery expression "//Programmer". If the hierarchy is fixed or if you would like to just retrieve any Programmers that are listed under  then you will have to specify that path in the XQuery accordingly:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY('/Company/Employee/Programmer'
                PASSING xmlcol RETURNING CONTENT)
  FROM XMLTEST;

<Programmer>
  <Salary>2000</Salary>
  <Facilities>
    <Car>bmw</Car>
    <Apartment>1</Apartment>
    <Bonus>2000</Bonus>
  </Facilities>
</Programmer>
```

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl. can you also tell me that, can i give another table column source path in side xml like:  `<Programmer>
  <Salary>source:TableSalary/AmountColumn</Salary>
<Programmer>` thanks

Comment: Not sure whether I fully understand that question. You mean that you extract the value for salary from an actual column from the table, or a different table?

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl.I was doing your insert into clause in sql developer and got this error: `ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method` how to fix this.

Comment: Which version of Oracle RDBMS are you using? I'm using 12.1.0.2 and it works fine. Perhaps you need an explicit conversion to `XMLTYPE` on a prior version, try to wrap a XMLTYPE() around your insert: `INSERT INTO XMLTEST (xmlcol) VALUES (XMLTYPE('......'));`

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl. i am using 11g

Comment: As to your question of retrieving relational data and put it onto the XML document, yes, you can do that. But it depends whether you would like to generate the XML out of relational altogether, just replace the salary with a relational column in which case you have to join your table or whether you would like to actually update/replace the salary. I highly recommend that you have a look at the [XML Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB4230) that takes you through all of the scenarios or your create a new questions with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl. It is very helpful resource.However i also try to convert data like using `XMLTYPE('......')`.But  still no row inserted.Thanks

Comment: Still the same error? Can you try with SQL*Plus? It runs fine on LiveSQL and that is the only environment that I currently have by hand: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/cv9ym8bj8cmtm2hx488mgc4j8

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl. I just try on live oracle and it worked. i wonder why its not working on my pc.Does XMLQUERY supports 11g.

Comment: Yes, it does. The documentation I have mentioned above is for 11g and besides, you stated that the `INSERT` statement threw an error and not the XQuery. I recommend that you have a look at the documentation, you should find the answers you need in there.

Comment: Thanks @gvenzl. Last thing i already told you about taking data from another table.If you get such examples then please let me know.thanks a lot.

Comment: As I have told you above, it does depend what you are trying to do. But as that is a different question altogether, please create a new question with a detailed explanation, including what the data model and data would look like. Thx,